# 'IntlDateFormatter' not found in /lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php

Tags: magento2, aws

I got that error while open magento 2 store on online server

```
 Fatal error: Class 'IntlDateFormatter' not found in /var/www/html/yourParts/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 111
```

I've installed and enabled intl extension

php version is 5.6

Comment: Which specific Magento version are you using? I guess you should update your PHP version to 7.1.24

Comment: I use magento 2.1.15. but when I ran composer install it told me  that php 7.1 not proper version

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to install Magento 2.1 by command line?

If yes, please check your php version:

```
 $ php -v
PHP 7.1.19-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Jul  9 2018 13:14:18) ( NTS )
```

Check either intl plugin is installed:

```
php -i | grep intl
/etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-intl.ini,
intl
intl.default_locale => no value => no value
intl.error_level => 0 => 0
intl.use_exceptions => 0 => 0
```

If not, please try to install intl plugin: (Linux)

```
sudo apt-get install php7.1-intl
```

See more detail [here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/prereq/php-ubuntu.html)

Cheers